# Как передать аргументы в слот, которых нет в сигнале?

Tags: c++, qt

Стоит задача из отдельного потока вызвать слот другого класса. пытаюсь сделать так:

```
MakePost *SendPost = new MakePost (); 

QThread *PostThread = new QThread;
SendPost->moveToThread(PostThread);

connect(PostThread, SIGNAL(started()), MakePost, SLOT(MakePostSignal ("GetSett", "/test.php", "test=1"))); 

PostThread->start();
```

и получаю ошибку:

> QObject::connect: No such slot MakePost::MakePostSignal ("GetSett",
>   "/test.php", "test=1")

, хотя в MakePost.h есть

```
public slots:
   void MakePostSignal(QString, QString, QByteArray);
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так, как передать значения в слот?.... Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Если у Вас Qt5, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
MakePost *SendPost = new MakePost ();
QThread *PostThread = new QThread;
SendPost->moveToThread(PostThread);
connect(PostThread, &QThread::started, MakePost, [MakePost]
{
    MakePost->MakePostSignal("GetSett", "/test.php", "test=1");
});
PostThread->start();
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если у нему в MakePostSignal есть сигнал который вызывает слот из MainWindow, как к нему правильно обратиться из потока?...

Comment: Кстати хороший вопрос: в каком контексте будет лямбда выполнятся? Это при том, что в лямбде можно `emit` перед вызовом `MakePostSignal` добавить и выпонять его в правильном контексте.

Comment: @user4150916, ничего не понял, перефразируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: @Cerbo, в контексте объекта, переданного третьим аргументом.

Comment: немного не понял, так как вызвать слот MainWindow из потока?....

Comment: @user4150916, послушайт, я взял код из Вашего вопроса, и преобразовал его в тот, что будет работать. Что за слот из `MainWindow`? Этого нет в Вашем вопросе. Обновите Ваш вопрос, если вопрос смежный, если же он другой — тогда задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @Cerbo, `emit` это ничто, в буквальном смысле.

Answer (score 3):

В коннекте передать данные нельзя. Нужно сделать что-то типа такого:

```
class MyClass : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
    //...
    void foo(){
        MakePost *sendPost = new MakePost (); 
        QThread *postThread = new QThread;
        sendPost->moveToThread(postThread);
        connect(postThread, SIGNAL(started()),  
                this, SLOT(_start())); 
        connect(this, SIGNAL(start(QString, QString, QByteArray)),  
                sendPost, SLOT(MakePostSignal(QString, QString, QByteArray))); 
        PostThread->start();
    }
signals:
    void start(QString str1, QString str2, QByteArray arr);
private slots:
    void _start(){
        emit("GetSett", "/test.php", "test=1");
    } 
};
```

`this` принимает сигнал потока `started` и шлет сигнал `start`, который принимает объект `sendPost`

**UPD:** Или было бы лучше передавать нужные данные сразу в `MakePost`

```
class MyClass : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
    //...
    void foo(){
        MakePost *sendPost = new MakePost("GetSett", "/test.php", "test=1"); 
        QThread *postThread = new QThread;
        sendPost->moveToThread(postThread);
        connect(postThread, SIGNAL(started()),  
                sendPost, SLOT(MakePostSignal()));                
        PostThread->start();
    }
};
```

**PS:** В этом коде я никак не заботился об утечках памяти. Но вам следует это сделать. Можно это сделать так:

```
connect(sendPost, SIGNAL(finished()), postThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(sendPost, SIGNAL(finished()), sendPost, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

естественно для этого нужно добавить в `MakePost` сигнал `finished`

**PPS:** Посмотрите в сторону `QThreadPool` + `QRunnable` или `QtConcurrent::run()`. В ряде случаев они куда удобнее `QThread`

Comment: Спасибо! А как в слот _start() динамически подставлять данные?

Comment: @user4150916, а что мешает передать эти данные сразу в конструктор `MakePost`?. Сейчас подправлю пример

Comment: И при необходимости совершать POST запрос, каждый раз создавать new MakePost("GetSett", "/test.php", "test=1"); ? new MakePost("GetSett1", "/test.php", "test=1"); new MakePost("GetSett2", "/test.php", "test=1"); Разве это правильно?....

Comment: @user4150916, В коде, который вы написали в вопросе, и так каждый раз создается новый `MakePost` и `QThread`, если я правильно понял. Если хотите использовать один `MakePost`, тогда объявите его как поле класса, и когда захотите вызвать какой-нибудь его метод в отдельном потоке пишите `QtConcurrent::run(sendPost, &MakePost::MakePostSignal, "GetSett2", "/test.php", "test=1");`

Comment: А как создать MakePost, что бы в него передать параметры?....

Comment: @user4150916, объявите `MakePost` [как-то так](http://pastebin.com/dLhKU1E7) и передавайте

Comment: Не проще ли было сделать подключение через лямбда-функцию?

Answer (score 0):

*For Qt 5:*

**QButton.hpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#pragma once

template <class T, class T1>
class QButton : public T1
{
public:
    QButton(T arg);
    T Arg;
};

template <class T, class T1>
QButton<T, T1>::QButton(T arg)
    : T1()
{
    Arg = arg;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
auto sBtn = new QButton<ServerInfo*, QPushButton>(serverInfo);
connect(sBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(serverButtonClicked()));

void MyProgram::serverButtonClicked() // slot of class MyProgram
{
    auto server = ((QButton<ServerInfo*, QWidget>*)sender())->Arg;
    MessageBoxA(GetActiveWindow(), (LPCSTR)server->IP.c_str(), (LPCSTR)server->Name.c_str(), 0);
}
```